# Is it possible to render image in Blazor page?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my regular asp.net core application, I have a page that renders jpg images like this "/images/{imagekey}". The images are stored in all kinds of places like cloud, db, harddrive, etc. I use the imagekey to locate the image and render the output by changing the response type. Basically, any other pages could use this as the image src like this:

```
<img src="/images/JFOFP393J">
```

Can I do this in Blazor pages? I am using server-side by the way. If not, what would be an alternative? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes you can!
It is not a Blazor thing. YOu have to load and deliverin response the images from a kind of service.
Done that here https://blog.ppedv.de/post/Image-Handler-in-ASPNET-Core as thumbnail generator

Comment: Thanks Hannes! So basically it still needs a regular asp.net page, not a Blazor page, got it.

Comment: You should be able to call an Asp.Net API endpoint (which could return the bytes for the image) inside of a Blazor page.